# post upgrade to 22.04 login issues

Tags: upgrade, login, 22.04

I have upgraded my Dell Inspiron from 20.04 to 22.04 and since I have been unable to login to the GUI. I can get to a shell using the recovery image and su-ing from root to my user. I can change tty and login successfully. Everything seems to be working except the GUI presentation, including networking. The weird thing is that the logon screen is from the prior version, 20.04.

Comment: did the upgrade get interrupted in the middle? can you try to redo the upgrade?

Comment: Did you run: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt -f install` You may need to alternate the last two commands and run them more than once until there are no more errors.

Comment: Yes, it the install blew up because of a python setting. I tried running the upgrade again but I get a "There is no development version of an LTD available." error.

Comment: On the fourth iteration of the above 2commands, it seems to be doing auch more expansive edit than the first three. Maybe I'm finally getting out of these weeds.

Comment: There was some progress. The login screen does display the correct version now. However, I am still able to login because after entering the password, I get the error "Failed to start session".